# How to use interpolation to make upload path dynamic paperclip ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, jquery-file-upload

I have following model and controller setup on my app

```
attr_accessible :upload
  has_attached_file :upload,
    :url => "/files/docs/:basename.:extension"
    :path => "/files/docs/:basename.:extension"

  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  def to_jq_upload
    {
      "name" => read_attribute(:upload_file_name),
      "size" => read_attribute(:upload_file_size),
      "url" => upload.url(:original),
      "delete_url" => upload_path(self),
      "delete_type" => "DELETE" 
    }
  end
```

and controller

```
def create
    @upload = Upload.new(params[:upload])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @upload.save
        format.html {
          render :json => [@upload.to_jq_upload].to_json,
          :content_type => 'text/html',
          :layout => false
        }
        format.json { render json: {files: [@upload.to_jq_upload],param:params}, status: :created, location: @upload }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @upload.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

now I want to upload my files to different folders like docs, images etc, so I need to make /docs dynamic in path

In file upload form I have added a hidden field with name folder and set value "docs" but when I use it in model to make path dynamic it gives me error following is the code I tried

```
has_attached_file :upload,
    :url => "/files/#{params[:folder]}/:basename.:extension"
    :path => "/files/#{params[:folder]}/:basename.:extension"
```

when I check I can see folder name in params but I am not able to use it in model.

I also tried interpolation

```
Paperclip.interpolates :folder do |attachment, style|
    attachment.instance.params[:folder]
  end
```

but no result.

Is there any way to make path dynamic using params ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes to get your desired result.

1. Add the field `folder` to your model so that it gets saved when you save your form.
2. Update your model and remove the `path` and `url` options form `has_attached_file`:

   ```
   has_attached_file: :upload
   ```
3. Update your environment (e.g. `config/environments/development.rb`) configuration of paperclip to use the interpolation and a dynamic path:

   ```
   # Paperclip defaults
   config.paperclip_defaults = {
         # other paperclip options for storage type e.g. file or S3

         # important part
         path: '/files/:dynamic_path'
   }
   ```
4. Implement the interpolation to create your dynamic path within your `config/initializers/paperclip.rb` initializer

   ```
   Paperclip.interpolates :dynamic_path do |attachment, style|
     file_name = attachment.original_filename.gsub(/#{File.extname(attachment.original_filename)}$/, '')
     folder = attachment.instance.folder
     "#{folder}/#{file_name}"
   end
   ```